# How to remove space from ToggleButtons in Flutter and make it scroll

Tags: user-interface, flutter, togglebutton

In the ToggleButtons-Example there is not much space between the icons:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleButtons-class.html

[image]

When I use the code provided, I get that

[image]

How can I remove the space on the left and on the right?

And is it possible scroll the toggleButtons - or even to "page" them (clicking f. e. on buttons on the left and on the right of the toggle buttons and "scroll/move" by one icon in a direction)?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**How can I remove the space on the left and on the right?**

How Bogdan Orzea said, in Flutter last release (version 1.9.1) isn't possible to change the padding of the ToggleButtons's children. Probably in the next Flutter release it will be possible. If you can't wait until the next release, you can update Flutter to version 1.12.13+hotfix.3 (beta). In this beta version the ToggleButtons's children will be square like is shown in ToggleButtons-Example, and you can change the padding using Padding Widget, like the code below:

```
ToggleButtons(
  children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
      child: Text('Option 1')
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
      child: Text('Option 2')
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
      child: Text('Option 3')
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
      child: Text('Option 4')
    )
  ],
)
```

**And is it possible scroll the toggleButtons - or even to "page" them (clicking f. e. on buttons on the left and on the right of the toggle buttons and "scroll/move" by one icon in a direction)?**

Wrap your ToggleButton inside the SingleChildScrollView widget:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: ToggleButtons(
    children: (...)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap any widget with a `SingleChildScrollView` like this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: ToggleButtons( ... ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the next Flutter release will include a PR that adds *constraints* parameter to *ToggleButtons* widget (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/39857). Until then, you can use the SingleChildScrollView method.

Comment: Do you have any idea in which version this was added?

Comment: It was released in version 1.12.13 (stable channel). Here is the complete changelog: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/release-notes-1.12.13.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are now built-in way to achieve that. Working solution in 2022:

```
Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                      child:
ToggleButtons(
                                        constraints:
                                            BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 55), // this line prevents excess vertical padding and allow you to set your own value here
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                  horizontal: 5),
                                              child: Text('ON')),
                                          Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                  horizontal: 5),
                                              child: Text('OFF')),
                                        ],
                                        isSelected: _isToggleActive,
                                        onPressed: (int index) async {
                                          // do something
                                          setState(() {});
                                        },
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        selectedColor:
                                            Color.fromARGB(255, 248, 246, 246),
                                        fillColor:
                                            Color.fromARGB(255, 38, 162, 67),
                                        borderColor:
                                            Color.fromARGB(255, 250, 251, 252),
                                        selectedBorderColor:
                                            Color.fromARGB(255, 20, 20, 20),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(10)),
                                      )),
```